# How can I query a ScalarListType in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I want to insert an integer list as a one column datatype in flask_sqlalchemy,
and I found [`ScalarListType` in the package SQLAlchemy-Utils](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.scalar_list):

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import ScalarListType 

class Foo():
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    list = db.Column(ScalarListType(int))
```

I can query for foo by id:

```
foo = Foo.query.filter(Foo.id==1).first()
```

Then, foo.list is an integer list like `[0, 0, 1, 0]`

But, how can I build a query for an index in the list? E.g. something like `Foo.list[3]==1`

I can't find any clue, help me please！

Comment: What happens when you try `foo.list[3]`? Or, are you just trying to find the index where the list has a `1`?

Comment: when I try `foos = Foo.query.filter_by(Foo.list[3]==1).all()`,I got the error `NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression`,I can see the datatype of list in pgAdmin is text. foo.list may have more than one 1

Comment: Just to narrow down the question a little further: are you trying to find out whether the list has a `1` in the 3rd index, so you can filter by that before it's been retrieved from the database?

Comment: Hey there I edited the question a little -- does that still describe what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a ScalarListType will be able to accomplish what you want -- it doesn't look like it's built to be queried by index. See [the source code here](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/scalar_list.html#ScalarListType) -- it's just a text column with commas separating the values.

You might be able to hack something together with bare SQL, but it would probably mean using [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) somewhere, or splitting strings which [gets complicated quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x).

In the long run, you might be better off just making a separate columns for this data.